# Tosca: How to scan Dropdown textbox which disapper upon opening xScan

Tags: testing, automated-tests, tosca

I have a problem in scanning a drop-down menu which disappears upon opening the xScan. I need to get the module id of the dropdown menu to verify some test steps. 
Do you have any solution with this if it is not really possible to get the module id of the dropdown menu?

Comment: Can you specify which "technology" the dropdown control is made from?  is it a windows control or a web page element?

Comment: Hello! Trimble epic. Thanks for the reply. It is a web page element. Once I insert a value in a textbox result will be shown with a drop-down menu. However, upon trying to scan the dropdown it disappears after opening xScan. I want to verify that the value of the inserted value in the textbox is equal to the value of the dropdown result. I believe that dropdown menu is not a module, I think it is a CSS. Hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Open developer tools in your browser of choice (F12), navigate to the console and input the following code:

```js
var fulldoc='';
var scrollX=0;
var scrollY=0;

document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
    if(event.key=='q' && event.altKey){
        fulldoc=document.body.outerHTML;
        scrollY=window.pageYOffset;
        scrollX=window.pageXOffset;
    }
    if(event.key=='w' && event.altKey){
        document.body.outerHTML=fulldoc;
        document.body.scrollTo(scrollX,scrollY);
    }
});
```

When the window looks the way you would want to scan, press 'Alt + Q', then press 'Alt + W'.
Now your window will freeze and then you can scan your page.
To steer the objects you need to refresh your browser.

Comment: This worked great for us, and was very useful for a PoC involving microsoft-dynamics - on clicking the sitemap button, the menu that popups was disappearing, and this helped to stabilise the menu and scan). Thanks @Jasmeet

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue with below 2 steps

1 - Add some text in textbox which will populate the dropdown below it .

2 - Use Send Keys Module to scroll down and select the value.

Comment: But what module should I use to verify the value? I will not perform a scan? What will be the element of the value which has been populated? DIV? SPAN?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where we had a popup that only appeared when clicking on a text box. The solution we received from the Tricentis trainer was as follows:

Part One
1. Open your application in Chrome
2. Right click the inspect
3. In the inspector window, on the Elements tab, navigate to your html element where it should be (you can do that by clicking on the element and check that you can see the html in the element)
4. Use the debugger to add a break point there, this should pause it and you should be able to see the elements you need to steer it.
5. Once you found the element, you will need the type of element (e.g. div, span, etc), and the class name

Part two
1. Rescan your module and select any element that matches the criteria of your element selected in Part One #5 
2. Identify it by only it's class name property and tag
3. Save and close
4. Edit the element in the module view by changing the class name. This should help you steer it

Note: if the element class name is not unique, you might need to use Explicit name.

Good luck